# I have written right code i think but not getting output in text area

Tags: java

**the code is written in netbeans 8.2**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
  int a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
  int b=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
  int c=a+b;
  jTextArea1.setText("addition is"+c);
}
```

and error is coming somewhat like this-- pls tell wats the mistake-

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "          3"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at addsf.jButton1ActionPerformed(addsf.java:95)
    at addsf.access$000(addsf.java:11)
```

and many much more is written.
Pls guide.

Comment: There is a space in your `String` , consider calling `trim()` on it.

Comment: You have a leading space in " 3"

Comment: Have you done anything to maybe understand the problem?

Comment: In the future, try to read the error message more critically as it usually will tell you exactly what is wrong, where and why, as it's doing in this situation. Note that if this were my GUI, I'd try to make things more idiot proof by presenting the user with an input component that won't allow wrong input, such as a JSpinner, or a JFormattedTextField, or a JTextField that uses a DocumentFilter to allow only numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse an integer, which should be only digits, nothing else.  Try this:

```
jTextField1.getText().trim())
```

which will essentially remove all whitespace before and after your string.
`"   2   "` becomes `"2"`.

However this is also prone to error if it is not a series of digits, in which case you should use a try/catch block.

Comment: i am from india and of 15 years ..i am new in this field thanks for helping but can you tell me that why we have to use trim()???

Comment: In my other laptop if i write the same code as i have written above it works but in other laptop it won't ...can u answer?

Comment: There is no way to tell why you have extra spaces in the string, however you should always treat input as error prone.

Comment: i am not able to find the space in string that you are telling me pls tell where is it?

Comment: i have not given any spaces by myself

Answer (score 0):

Exception message is saying to you, that there is something wrong with your input:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 3"

If you look at the string you can spot the white-space in front of 3 which is the cause of exception.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(" 3"); // leading white-space causes error
int b = Integer.parseInt("3"); // OK
```

To remove possible white-spaces from your input, you can use method `String#trim();` which returns new `String` without leading or trailing white-spaces.

```
int c = Integer.parseInt(" 3".trim());
```

Or you can use `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement);` which replaces all sequences of string that matches given reular expression by specified replacement.

```
int d = Integer.parseInt(" 3".replaceAll("\\s", "")); // \\s = white-space
```

Consider to use `JFormattedTextField` instead of `JTextField`. `JTextField` accepts anything you write into it (number with letters/white-spaces), whereas on `JFormattedTextField` you can apply mask, which accepts only numbers, so user would not be able to insert letters. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084104/accept-only-numbers-and-a-dot-in-java-textfield#answer-18084146).